# Evaluating series for $e^x$, but with a $\log$ thrown in

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

The following series came up, and I'm wondering (hoping!) it can be solved.  It is the same as the well-known series for $e^x$, except it has a logarithm term added:$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}\log(k)
$$How, if possible, can I evaluate this in closed-form?

Comment: I doubt this has a closed form. Most series with logarithmic terms don't.

Comment: I suppose that it starts at $k=1$.

Comment: Might be something from this, but I wouldn't hold out... Mother Goddess Mathematics tends to not like closed forms...

Comment: The point is: can you think of a function $g(x)$ such that $g^{(k)}(0)=\log k$ for all $k\ge1$? Personally, nothing comes to mind.

Comment: A similar question was discussed in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143250/evaluating-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1) concerning $x\to\infty$

Comment: You have to start the sum at 1 because the log of 0 is not defined.

Comment: @imallett [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+x%5Ek%2Fk!++*+log+k+from+k%3D1+to+infinity) says that the series converges by the ratio test, so you can calculate a numerical approximation.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237519/information-on-the-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac-log-nn?rq=1) for the $x=1$ case. A similar formula can be worked out as the derivative of the [Bell Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) using (12). As to what constitutes a "closed form" is a different matter. Also known as the [Touchard Polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials#Generalizations), they have a non-integral order $n$ generalization, which would be needed for differentiation.

Comment: Regarding the $k=0,1$ error, I actually should have written $\log^k(A)$, but a copying error made me think it was $\log(k) A$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\log(k)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-kt}}t~\mathrm dt$$

And so, assuming you intend to start at $k=1$,

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-kt}}t~\mathrm dt$$

The sum isn't hard to evaluate and comes out to

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{x-t}-e^{xe^{-t}}}t-1\right)~\mathrm dt$$

That $e^{xe^{-t}}$ makes it fairly clear that I would doubt on any closed form.